# in IE browser page properties window shows size : not Available?

Tags: iframe, internet-explorer-7, fiddler

in fiddler i can see content length for page but in IE browser page properties window shows size : not Available.

Can anyone help me why its happening?

Thanks
Krishna

Answer (score 1):

Internet Explorer gets the information in a fundamentally different way than Fiddler does-- it's looking at the size of the cache file. If the cache file isn't available (e.g. the file wasn't cacheable) the information isn't available. Generally, what Fiddler shows you is what you want anyway.

Comment: @Eric:Is there any methods by which i can get page size?i am using SHDocVw.DWebBrowserEvents in my webbrowser control.

Comment: Thanks Eric. Understand that. 
Can we in any way get what the page size, similar to fiddler, via any of the APIs or Events that IE exposes?

Comment: Can you explain what you hope to do with this information? The page size shown won't include any of the dependent resources like CSS, JS, etc, so it's not terribly useful. You could approximate by getting the length of the document's outerHTML string...

Comment: @Eric: Can we get size of resources like CSS,JS,Images etc using IE APIs or events?

Comment: Not via any property on the DOM, no. The closest you could come is find all URLs in the page and call WinINET APIs to see if the item is still in the cache. You might save some time by explaining what overall goal you're trying to achieve and why using Fiddler/FiddlerCore won't work for you.

Comment: @Eric : actually i have WPF application containing webbrowser control.I want to monitor different intranet web application used by user using this application. main aim is to get performance of web application so parameters like page size ,request start time ,end time etc. are required. fiddler/fiddlercore behaves like proxy if anything goes wrong then user will not able to do anything. we want monitor only application access using wpf application. hope you get my problem.